# Sphinx and Markdown .md links

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx

I'm trying to convert Markdown files to html using Sphinx but am having trouble getting `[links](another.md)` to be translated to `<a href="another.html">links</a>`, rather the extension of the target remains the original `.md` and appears as `<a href="another.md">links</a>`.

I've created a simple example...

**test.md**

```
[Test link](https://www.stackoverflow.com)

[Another Markdown doc](another.md)
```

**another.md**

```
# Another test markdown
```

Both files reside in the top level directory and I run `sphinx-quickstart` to create `conf.py`, accepting the defaults.  I then modify `conf.py` to have...

```
from recommonmark.parser import CommonMarkParser
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
]
source_suffix = ['.rst', '.md']
source_parsers = {
    '.md': CommonMarkParser,
}
```

The resulting html files are produced but the link from `test.html` to `another.html` is not correct and appears as...

**test.html**

```
...
<p><a class="reference external" href="https://thefloow.com">Test link</a></p>
<p><a class="reference external" href="another.md">A real test</a></p>
...
```

...and points to `another.md` rather than `another.html`.  I asked a few days ago and was pointed towards using recommonmark's `AutoStructify` (see thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52429549/sphinx-documentation-and-links-to-markdown/52430829)) but that didn't work and on further digging/reading it turns out that [`enable_auto_doc_ref` is now deprecated](https://github.com/rtfd/recommonmark) and [`.md` links are added as `:any:` and should be handled by Sphinx](https://github.com/rtfd/recommonmark/issues/85#issuecomment-327810549).

But I don't understand why this isn't working or what I should do to resolve it.  Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

**EDIT**

Versions are as follows

- Sphinx 1.8.0
- recommonmark 0.4.0

Comment: What is the version of sphinx and what is the version of recommonmark? The feature is relatively recent so it is important to know.

Comment: Apologies for the omission, Sphinx is `1.8.0` whilst recommonmark is `0.4.0`.

Comment: I'm having similar issues. Were you able to resolve this? I also realized its been deprecated and I can not find any new information of how Sphinx is supposed to "natively" convert the links. I did find an example in Recommonmark's docs of how to generate links (https://github.com/rtfd/recommonmark/blob/master/docs/auto_structify.md). It does seem to work for them with the `API Reference` link but I cannot replicate it.

Comment: Scratch my comment about the recommonmark docs, seems like they use `AutoStructify` and the deprecated method to resolve the links.

Comment: @MarcusLind no I didn't manage to get this working I'm afraid (slipped down my ToDo list).  Please do report back if you work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`recommonmark==0.5.0.dev0` solves this problem.

`conf.py` configuration

```
extensions = [
    # other
    'recommonmark',
]

source_suffix = ['.rst', '.md']
```

`pip` configuration (`requirements.txt`)

```
sphinx==1.8.2
# recommonmark==0.5.0.dev0
git+https://github.com/rtfd/recommonmark
```

Please refer to https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/markdown.html if you need more details.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up I'll have a look later this week.

Comment: This worked. However, when there are relative links to sections in a different Markdown document, For instance, the text "See [here](05-osm-usage.md#fault-management)", translates to "See <a class="reference external" href="05-osm-usage.md#fault-management">here</a>".
There seems to be a bug in recommonmark.

Comment: @garciadeblas I'm experiencing that same issue as well - were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @garciadeblas I opened [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68744271/sphinx-docs-linking-to-specific-section-of-another-markdown-page) about this.  Let me know if you've found a solution, or possibly this should be reported as a bug.