# Sphinx Recommonmark CommonMarkParser does not detect URL link

Tags: markdown, python-sphinx, myst

I am using Sphinx to build a documentation out of Markdown files.
The documentation is pretty clear that myst-parser should handle markdown links in the typical `[some text](www.example.com)` manner.

Subsequently I installed myst-parser, set the extension `extensions = ['myst_parser']` and specified the source_suffix:

```py
source_suffix = {
    '.rst': 'restructuredtext',
    '.txt': 'markdown',
    '.md': 'markdown',
}
```

Unfortunately the links did not get converted correctly and are just displayed written out as the following HTML:

```html
[some text](<a class="reference external" href="www.example.com">www.example.com</a>)
```

This is then displayed in the following manner `[some text](www.example.com)` in the browser, which is clearly not the intended link.

I also tried to use Recommonmark in the following manner:

```py
from recommonmark.parser import CommonMarkParser

source_parsers = {
    '.md': CommonMarkParser,
}

source_suffix = ['.rst', '.md']
```

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54004004/5060208) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33797841/5060208), but ended up with the same output.
How can this rather simple issue be fixed?

Versions being used:
recommonmark 0.7.1
myst-parser 0.13.6
sphinx 3.5.4
python 3.9.2

EDIT
Find here the updated conf.py file

```
# Configuration file for the Sphinx documentation builder.
#
# This file only contains a selection of the most common options. For a full
# list see the documentation:
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html

# -- Path setup --------------------------------------------------------------
import sphinx_rtd_theme
import sys
import os

print("CURRENT WORKING DIRECTORY")
print(os.getcwd())
print('adding path')
sys.path.insert(0, r'path_to_repo')
print(sys.path)

# At top on conf.py (with other import statements)
import recommonmark
from recommonmark.transform import AutoStructify
from recommonmark.parser import CommonMarkParser

# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------
project = 'py_neuromodulation'
copyright = '2021, John Doe'
author = 'John Doe'

source_parsers = {
    '.md': 'recommonmark.parser.CommonMarkParser',
}
source_suffix = ['.rst', '.md']
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.autosummary',
    'sphinx.ext.doctest',
    'sphinx.ext.intersphinx',
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
    'numpydoc',
    'sphinx_rtd_theme',
    'sphinx.ext.napoleon',
    'recommonmark'
]

autosummary_generate = True
html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'
html_static_path = ['_static']

# At the bottom of conf.py
def setup(app):
    app.add_config_value('recommonmark_config', {
            'url_resolver': lambda url: github_doc_root + url,
            'auto_toc_tree_section': 'Contents',
            }, True)
    app.add_transform(AutoStructify)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not solve the problem, I added the conf.py for more details

Comment: Notice that recommonmark is deprecated in favor of myst-parser https://github.com/readthedocs/recommonmark/issues/221

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, you must include a protocol for external links.

However if you want to use bare links without the protocol, then use [Linkify](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/syntax-optional.html#linkify):

> Adding "`linkify`" to `myst_enable_extensions` (in the sphinx `conf.py` [configuration file](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html)) will automatically identify “bare” web URLs and add hyperlinks:
>
> `www.example.com` -> [www.example.com](https://www.example.com)
>
> This extension requires that [`linkify-it-py`](https://github.com/tsutsu3/linkify-it-py) is installed. Either directly; `pip install linkify-it-py` or via `pip install myst-parser[linkify]`.

The following code example demonstrates what the documentation describes.

```python
myst_enable_extensions = [
    "linkify",
]
```

Comment: This is unfortunately not solving the mentioned problem that markdown links are not supported in the [text](link) manner. I tried to outline above that recommonmark should in theory fix this, but also the AutoStructify [url resolver](https://recommonmark.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_structify.html#url-resolver)  leads to the same result

Comment: Your `conf.py` does not show that you have added `linkify`. Did you try it, as described in MyST's documentation?