# Sphinx Docs - Linking to Specific Section of Another Markdown Page

Tags: markdown, documentation, python-sphinx

**Currently** markdown links to other MD docs are working fine (and same with section links within the same document), e.g.:

`doc1.md`

```
# Doc 1

See [doc2](./doc2.md) [LINK WORKS] for more details.
```

`doc2.md`

```
# Doc 2

See [section 2](#section-2) [LINK WORKS]

# Section-2

<details>
```

### Issue => Linking to section of another doc (in Sphinx Only)

Linking to a specific section of another doc isn't working, as the html is rendered with an anchor to `/doc2.md#section-2` instead of `/doc2.html#section-2`, which results in a `404`.  This works fine in VS Code's MD preview, on Github, etc.

** Is this a known issue?  If not, how can I fix this?**

`doc1.md`

```
# Doc 1

See [section2 of doc2](./doc2.md#section-2) [LINK DOESN'T WORK] for more details.
```

`doc2.md`

```
# Doc 2

See [section 2](#section-2) [LINK WORKS]

# Section-2

<details>
```

#### Specs

- Conda Environment / Python3
- Sphinx 3.4.3
- recommonmark 0.7.1

Also, here's a [Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52496591/sphinx-and-markdown-md-links), but different issue.

Comment: Which Sphinx extension are you using to parse Markdown files? MyST? RecommonMark? Other? Anyway, you could change the target to `(./doc2.html#section-2)` or better use [MyST syntax](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/syntax/syntax.html#syntax-targets).

Comment: @StevePiercy I'm using recommonmark for parsing markdown (as mentioned in the question).  The problem with changing the target to point to `.html` is then these links won't work in Github.  My temporary solution is to remove references to sections in other docs and just link to the page, although not 100% ideal.

Comment: @StevePiercy also I am looking into MyST now, so thanks for that recommendation!

Comment: Choose one for correct linkage: rendering by GitHub or Sphinx. Cannot do both.

Comment: @StevePiercy thanks for the pointer that MyST has special support for labels.  I think this would be worth being an answer.